CORS error when redirecting from server to client using spring Boot 2.7.10 with Spring Security enabled
I have two applications:

Spring boot application as backend server running on http://localhost:8080/server
Javascript client running on http://localhost:9000/app

Client on http://localhost:9000/app can login via a customized loginform with credentials and send requests (e.g. using javascript fetch() API to receive JSON data from server) fine to web application on port 8080, however, when user clicked on logout button, it sends a request to the backend like below http://localhost:8080/server?originalClientURL=http://localhost:9000/app. The server can process the request and it redirects web browser (Chrome) back to client with the error below:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:900/app/' 
(redirected from 'http://localhost:8080/server/logout?originalClientURL=http://localhost:9000/app/') 
from origin 'http://localhost:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.


I've tried many solutions found on StackOverFlow but they don't work. Here is what I have in my Spring application:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(request -> {
                CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
                configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
                configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
                configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
                return configuration;
            }))
                    .csrf()
                    .disable();

            http
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")) // -- to avoid the CRSF logout form by Spring with POST
                .addLogoutHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                
                    // Do some stuffs on the server before redirecting back to the requesting client
                        

                    // Redirect back to this endpoint afterwards
                    String originalClientURL = httpServletRequest.getParameterMap().get(ORIGINAL_CLIENT_URL)[0];
                    httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(originalClientURL);

        });
    
    }

}



What is running on port 900? Why do you call 'http://localhost:900/app/'. Looks like you configured something wrong.

@dur it is on port 9000, a javascript client which connects to backend web application on port 8000. I don't think there is something wrong with configurations, but it is about the nature of HTTP redirection request.

Then, why is your error message: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:900/app/'? Still looks like a configuration problem.
